# A Trigonometric Functions integration by separation of variables

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, derivatives

I have to solve this question using the separation of variables method but I am unable to separate $dy$ and $dx$ from these trigonometric functions.

$\sec^2x\,dy + \csc y\,dx=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\operatorname{sec}^2xdy=-\operatorname{cosec}ydx$$

$$\int\frac{1}{\operatorname{cosec}y}dy=-\int\frac{1}{\operatorname{sec}^2x}dx$$

$$\int \sin y\,dy=-\int\cos^2x\,dx$$

Can you do it now?

Edit: In case you get stuck:

$\frac{d}{dy}(-\cos y) = \sin y\implies \int\sin y\,dy=-\cos y +C$

$\cos 2x = \cos^2x-\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1\implies \cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}(\cos2x+1)$

$\int\cos^2x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\cos2x+1\,dx = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}\sin2x+x)+C'$

Then $$-\cos y = -\frac{1}{4}\sin 2x-\frac{1}{2}x+C''$$

$$\cos y=\frac{1}{4}\sin2x+\frac{x}{2}+A$$

Note I just changed the arbitrary constants each time to indicate that they are different.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Replace $\sec x$ and $\csc y$ with $\dfrac1{\cos x}$ and $\dfrac1{\sin y}$  respectively.

Comment: May I know why this downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$\sec^2 x dy = -\csc y dx$

$\frac 1{\csc y} dy = - \frac 1{\sec^2 x} dx$

$\sin y dy = - \cos^2 x dx$

Now integrate it.